# A fee for entering a convention

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the name for a fee paid for entrance to a convention or other similar event?

Comment: You mean entry fee?

Comment: ***Entrance fee***
noun [C] UK    US          
› an amount of money that you pay in order to be allowed into a cinema, theatre, etc.
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/entrance-fee

Comment: I've never heard "entrance fee" used in that sense before, only in the sense of entering a competition. It may just be a regional thing, though.

Comment: It is also called an _admission (charge)_, usually shortened to "admission" e.g. "They charge $10 admission."

Comment: Specifically for conventions that are "shows", where _exhibitors_ have _booths_, there are _exhibitor fees_, which are different than visitors' _admission (charge)_

Comment: It would help if you clarified what you mean by "similar event", as terms may vary. For example, a movie theater has a _ticket price_, not an entrance or admission charge (in AmE).

Comment: You really need to specify _what kind_ of entrance you're talking about, and _who_ pays it. Like Brian said, there are frequently different fees for exhibitors/contributors and regular visitors, and there are also often different fees for simple visits to the convention space itself and to exhibitions/events that take place at the convention.

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps the most usual term in the UK for something people attend as a spectator is ***admission fee***.

Where there is a competition or examination involved ***entry fee*** would seem more appropriate.

In the case of a convention I think either could arguably be used.

Answer (score 1):

***Admission fee*** could be one. ***Registration fee*** or ***entrance fee*** are also possible answers.

Answer (score 0):

Our company's three multi-day national conventions (U.S.) would call that *a registration fee.* You probably won't be allowed admittance to any convention without first registering and receiving an attendee badge, even if you wait to register until you arrive at the door of the convention.

If you Google the phrase *convention registration fee*, it seems to be standard terminology for professional conventions. [[*Convention*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/convention): a large meeting or conference, especially of members of a political party or a particular profession.]